# Looking for a 90s Macintosh background pattern collection

Tags: apple-macintosh, identify-this-software, utilities

I've been trying to find a collection of desktop patterns for Macintosh that I had for System 7 back in the day.
I remember it as a specific application that you ran to set the patterns (as opposed to how desktop backgrounds tend to work today.)

Patterns I remember from it:

- Escher's [Reptiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reptiles_(M._C._Escher)) pattern, in Black and White I think
- Blue, pseudo-3D spheres organised in a grid
- Other, tiled pseudo-3D patterns in general

I realise this is a pretty vague description, but I've been lucky with those here before so I thought I'd try. I've been looking through the Macintosh Repository without luck so far.

Comment: It might be a resource (`pat#`, `ppat`, etc.) built into the System file.  As such, it would not be found as a stand-alone file.

Comment: heh - I very vaguely remember the same; but couldn't even put it in a decade!

Answer (score 5):

I don't remember if it contains those specific backgrounds, but one pack that otherwise matches your description is included among the freeware bundled with the Demo releases of [Executor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executor_(software)) from before it got open-sourced.

I believe it's called "Desktop Textures Vol. 1", which would suggest that what you're looking for is Desktop Textures ([III](http://www.avernus.com/desktop-textures/), [2.1](https://www.macintoshrepository.org/25881-desktop-textures-installer-2-1-7-pattern-databases-)) and one of the many community-contributed texture packs.

(Maybe start by trawling the Wayback machine for the ones mentioned [here](http://www.avernus.com/desktop-textures/third-party-textures.html) such as [Iain's Desktop Textures Volumes I through V](https://web.archive.org/web/20070721001759/http://www.ecn.net.au/%7Eiain/mac_things.html))